# Id name mapping using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file with ids and names in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "type": "vis",
    "id": "8204af40-09e4-11ea-a775-a7174a3c3e58",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Age vs BMI"
    },
    "updated_at": "2019-11-19T08:28:29.499Z",
    "version": "WzIzLDFd"
  },
  {
    "type": "vis",
    "id": "96bb9ce0-09e5-11ea-a775-a7174a3c3e58",
    "attributes": {
      "title": " Age vs LDL"
    },
    "updated_at": "2019-11-19T08:28:29.499Z",
    "version": "WzI0LDFd"
  }
]
```

I would like to extract id-name mappings using jq. I want my output to look as follows:

```
{"Age vs BMI":"8204af40-09e4-11ea-a775-a7174a3c3e58", " Age vs LDL":"96bb9ce0-09e5-11ea-a775-a7174a3c3e58"}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a reduce-free solution:

```
INDEX(.[]; .attributes.title) | map_values(.id)
```

Comment: As you know INDEX/2 is implemented using reduce, what do you really mean reduce-free? And what's wrong with reduce? To me, with foreach they are probably the best constructs jq have

Comment: "reduce-free" here simply means that "reduce" does not appear (explicitly) in the solution. `reduce` and friends are syntactically not functional and are in some ways quite tricky (as evidenced, for example, by the variety of behaviors in different releases of jq).  They can be viewed as important but low-level building blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In case your jq is very old, here’s another reduce-free solution:

```
map( {(.attributes.title): .id} ) | add
```